# A method for loading the backbone stack with require

Tags: javascript

Here is how I would do it using plain HTML script tags per this [SO Question on CDN suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357806/backbone-js-underscore-js-cdn-recommendation).  This would be a serial load (underscore->jquery->backbone) that holds up the rest of the page.

```
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.10/backbone-min.js"></script>
```

How would I load these libraries using require.js or a similar non-blocking method?

**References ( links to the API )**

- [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)
- [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)
- [backbone](http://backbonejs.org/)
- [require](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jquery is AMD Friendly so you can just require it in your require.js config

Backbone and underscore are no longer AMD Friendly so you have these options:

1. You can either include them as "externals", with shim assigning the correct dependencies (see here [the docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) and a [tutorial](http://gregfranko.com/blog/require-dot-js-2-dot-0-shim-configuration/) )
2. Or you can use slightly altered versions of both libraries that are AMD enabled. You can find them in [this repository](https://github.com/amdjs).
3. Use an older version of backbone and underscore. (not recommended)

---

Note: If you opt for the shimming route, keep in mind that those libraries will not be load asynchronously.

---

Here's a working example using the **ALTERED VERSIONS** of the library:

```
require.config({
    enforceDefine: true, //Only libraries AMD Friendly will be loaded
    urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime(), //for development, forces browser to clear the cache
    paths: { // relative paths (to the current file main.js)
        "es5":               'libs/es5-shim/es5-shim',
        "jquery":            'libs/jquery/jquery',
        "jqueryThreeDots":   'libs/jquery/plugins/jquery.ThreeDots',//A jquery plugin
        "underscore":        'libs/underscore/underscore.amd',
        "underscore.string": 'libs/underscore/underscore.string',
        "backbone":          'libs/backbone/backbone.amd',
        "text":              'text',
        "mediator":          'libs/backbone/plugins/backbone.mediator',
        "bootstrap":         'libs/bootstrap/bootstrap.min',
        "rangy":             'libs/rangy/rangy-core.amd',
    },
    shim: {
        "bootstrap": {
            deps: ["jquery"],
            exports: "$.fn.popover"
        }
    }
});
```

An example with shim:

```
require.config({
    enforceDefine: true,
    urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime(),
    paths: {
        "jquery": 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'
    },
    shim: {
        backbone: {
            deps: ["underscore", "jquery"], // Backbone dependencies
            exports: "Backbone" // variable exported
        },
        underscore: {
            exports: "_"
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: No, like I said, this is an example of loading backbone and underscore ALTERED versions, downloaded from that repository.

Comment: Yes. Let me change the second example to a CDN

Comment: fyi, i don't think you need quotes around the keys in your object literals...all keys are strings and none are variables.

Comment: I don't. But I use the first part of the configuration file with a requirejs optimizer plugin that requires that.

Comment: why don't you define a `baseUrl` as the API mentions and as the answer below?

Comment: Because I don't need one since my base url is the location of main.js, which is assumed by default.

Comment: `<script data-main="scripts/main.js" src="scripts/require.js"></script>` - so you have this in your html?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24156/discussion-between-tivie-and-pure-code)

Answer (score 1):

This is how we include jQuery, Underscore and Backbone with Require in our projects:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "js",

    paths: {
        backbone: "backbone-min",
        jquery: "jquery.min",
        underscore: "underscore-min"
    },

    shim: {
        backbone: { deps: ["underscore", "jquery"], exports: "Backbone" },
        jquery: { exports: "jQuery" },
        underscore: { exports: "_" }
    }
});

requirejs(["backbone"], function (Backbone) {
    // Now we can reference not just Backbone but also jQuery and
    // underscore since those two are dependencies for Backbone.
});
```